# Memento design pattern with composite pattern

Tags: design-patterns, paint

I have a rectangle class that extend a form class, a composite class that extend form class and a memento class to do a roll back on x and y attributes of the form.

I have a canvas and I am drawing some shapes on it. By moving one shape it's ok. I can undo that move, by installing the memento.

The problem is when I group shapes in a composite object of forms and I move them, I can't find the way to roll back the move action by installing a memento. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: memento?  You need a minimum code example

Comment: Yup memento sorry

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to maintain one Memento for one specific state of the whole canvas, not for individual shapes which are on the canvas. This Memento could be one Composite object which contain immutable objects. When you change an object you don't change its properties but rather make a new one with the new properties and rebuild the whole Memento with the new situation.

It seems to be a bit memory consuming but you can optimize very well because immutable objects are quite-well reusable. You can reuse unchanged objects during creating the next Memento.

I'm not sure if it's understandable like this.
Immutability and one-memento-for-canvas are the important things.

Comment: So what I must do is a memento for the state of the canvas instead of the form desired to roll back so on undo I will get back the hol old canvas instead of getting the old form?

Comment: Exactly. As long as 'undo' concerns the whole canvas, the Memento should represent the contents of the whole canvas as well.